# Config class for class X, should it be nested in X or outside of X?

Tags: c++, c++11

Config class for class X, should it be nested in X or outside of X?

I have class X, and I need a class that will represent the configuration for an
X object. It is nice to have an X class, and then a public nested class
in X, called Config:

```
X a;
X::Config b;
```

I wonder, is it OK to have the Config class nested or should I have it outside of X?
Are there performance differences or anything else to watch out for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, it's entirely subjective.**

Personally I tend to go for the nested class, but I couldn't tell you why, beyond OCD and a tendency to encapsulate the frak out of everything.